# how to handel filling 2 table in rpt file(crystal report)?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, windows-runtime

i use crystal report in C# winform program. in rpt file,i set detail section in to multiple columns. i put two table in detail section and set "Across and Down" for it.i want to first one table is filled until page1 is finished, after this,after new page is start, second table is start to filling. and after second table is filled, new page(page2) is start. how do i do?
now, in run time, first record is put in table1, second record is put in table2, third record is put in table1 and so on.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing, but what you describe is down then across- have you tried that?

Comment: i put 2box in detail section for show data.my result data from dataset is 10 row,i want to box1 is filling, after than, box2 is starting to fill.in "across_down", two box asynchronous to filling, and in "down_across" just box1 is filled.

Comment: i want to in page1 in box1 is filled after than box2 start filling it.after than page2 is start!